# Have the sizes of the image of gold made of Nebuchadnezzar any significance?

Tags: history, historical-interpretation, daniel, babylon

> King Nebuchadnezzar made an image of gold, **sixty cubits high and six cubits wide**, and set it up on the plain of Dura in the province of Babylon. (Daniel 3:1)

Did these sizes represent something in the Babylon time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sizes didn't represent anything special themselves, but if you know them, then you know that this "image of gold" was not a mere statue - from the given proportions (10:1 ratio) you could conclude that it was an [obelisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obelisk). Obelisks in ancient world could have special meanings and purposes. Some of them were considered "sacred pillars". Pliny the Elder in *The Natural History* (Book 36, [Chapters 14](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3aabo%3aphi,0978,001:36:14)-15) describes them as objects often associated with Sun worphip. Similarily, Ammianus Marcellinus in his *Roman History* ([Book 17](http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/ammianus_17_book17.htm#C4)). There are conflicting opinions about how to interpret Hebrew words used by Daniel in this verse and not everyones agrees on the concept of obelisk, but the proportions of the image (10:1 ratio) suggest it strongly.

Answer (score 2):

The Bible is not very clear about any representation as to why the King built in its size. However, one thing is certain, he wanted to be worshiped like satan. The King wanted to make sure that the statue would be visible in all of the Babylonian kingdoms so that he placed it in a plain (Plains of Dura) where there would be lesser sight obstruction. Additionally, 60 cubits are approximately equivalent to 90 ft., or a 10-Storey building. By that, we can safely assume that the statue could be visible. So when the music starts all of the people inside Babylon would fall down and worship in the direction of the statue. Satan, just like Nebuchadnezzar, wanted worship. He brought Jesus in one of the highest building in the land and said that he would give all of the world's kingdom if Jesus would bow down and worship him. I hoped I answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Bible gives us no explicit reason for the statue's height or width. However, from the Babylonian's point of view, not the Bible's, it may be assumed that there was some theological, astrological, or mystical reason for its height being 60 cubits.

For example, the Babylonian numbering system is responsible for giving us 60 minutes in an hour and is a base 60 system without zeros. So essentially, this number is the zenith, the highest or at least the highest in a cycle.

Answer (score -1):

The image was 60 cubits long, 6 cubits wide and there were six instruments(cornet,flute,harp,sackbut,psaltery and dulcimer) to be played at the designated times of its worship. Dan 3:1-2&5.

All this corresponds to the Image of the beast that will be worshipped in Revelations 13:12-16. It also corresponds to 666. The number of the beast's name!!

Comment: If there is any such connection (which I personally doubt) it might explain why John used 666 as a symbol for his beast imagery in Revelation. It certainly doesn't answer the current question.